# Execute a processor when Async blocks finishes execution

Tags: mule

In mule within the parent flow i have used three sub flows, each subflow executes in a aysnchronous block. I wanted to execute a processor once each of subflow has completed processing. Can someone throw some light on how this can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `request-reply` and `collection-aggregator` message processors to implement such fork-join pattern with Mule.

Read more about the approach here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/aggregation-with-mule-fork-and-join-pattern/

Comment: David, I had a question here in case if any of my subflow is stuck , takes a long time to execute. How should this use case be handled.

Comment: Configure a time-out on the `collection-aggregator`.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to avoid the overhead of VM Queue's you can do it [this way](http://ricston.com/blog/simple-fast-parallel-processing-forkjoin-pattern-mule/)

The key is using the   which has the logic to accomplish the fork-join

```
<processor-chain>
<custom-processor class="com.ricston.processor.ParallelMessageProcessor" doc:name="ParallelMessageProcessor">
<spring:property name="processors">
<spring:list>
<spring:ref bean="lookupWs1"/>
<spring:ref bean="lookupWs2"/>
</spring:list>
</spring:property>
<spring:property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
</custom-processor>
<combine-collections-transformer />
</processor-chain>
```